# how to create column using awk with column name

Tags: linux, awk

I have csv file like following

```
 Name    Amount     Interest
 JB      10000       0.5
 Jefh    50000       1.25
 John    20000       0.25
```

I want to add a column using awk like follwoing

```
Name    Amount     Interest    Total Interest
 JB      10000       0.5        50
 Jefh    50000       1.25       625
 John    20000       0.25       50
```

I am using following command to achieve that

```
awk -F, '$8 > 0 {print $1,",",$2,",",$3,",",$2*$3}
```

but i am getting output as following because it is multiplying first line as well

```
Name    Amount     Interest     0
 JB      10000       0.5        50
 Jefh    50000       1.25       625
 John    20000       0.25       50
```

how can add column name instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first awk-command add:

```
NR==1 {print $0,"Total_Interest"; next}
```

This will work on the first line of input only, print a string, and jump to the next line / record

Hence, the entire call should look something like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0,"Total_Interest"; next}
         $8 > 0 {print $1,",",$2,",",$3,",",$2*$3}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{$(NF+1) = (NR==1 ? "Total Interest" : $2 * $3)} 1'
```

That adds a field for each line, then simply prints the line.