# How to extract columns then add new column by caculate in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have text file like below:

```
   ID   Grade1   Grade2  Grade3
 JK01       92       84      88
 JK02       87       80      93
 JK03       89       98      95
```

I want to extract specific column then add two column using awk.
`Weight` will from `Grade2 *1.5+2`,and `Note` is a specific number:`17`.
Desird Output like:

```
   ID   Grade2  Weight  Note
 JK01       84     134    17
 JK02       80     122    17
 JK03       98     149    17
```

I am using following command to achieve that

```
awk '{print $1,$3,$3*1.5+2, 17}' file.txt > file.tem.txt
```

But I got

```
ID Grade2 2 17
JK01 84 128 17
JK02 80 122 17
JK03 98 149 17
```

The header of `Weight` and `Note` not right.
And I also tried

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$3,"Weight", "Note"; next}
         {print $0,$2*1.5+2,17}' file.txt > file.tem.txt
```

form [how to create column using awk with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554590/how-to-create-column-using-awk-with-column-name), still can't get desird output.Any advice you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you instructing GNU `AWK` that you want `,` as field separator, whilst your file has not any `,` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } NR==1 { print $1, $3, "Weight", "Note" } NR>1 { weight = $3 * 1.5 + 2; print $1, $3, weight, "17" }' file.txt
```

output

```
ID  Grade2  Weight  Note
JK01  84     128     17
JK02  80     122     17
JK03  98     149     17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ awk '
    {
        $2 = $3;
        $3 = ($3+0==$3) ? $3*1.5+2 : "Weight";
        $4 = (NR>1) ? 17 : "Note"
    }1
' file | column -t
ID    Grade2  Weight  Note
JK01  84      128     17
JK02  80      122     17
JK03  98      149     17
```